# Price not updating on front end after API product update

Tags: api, message-queue, rabbit-mq

I have an issue in that whenever I update a product price using the asynchronous endpoint

```
POST http://base.test/rest/all/async/V1/products
```

(running Rabbit MQ), the price does not change on the product description page or listing page.

If I clear the BLOCK_HTML cache, it then shows OK.

This only happens with the asynchronous endpoint. Regular endpoint

```
 POST http://base.test/rest/all/V1/products
```

updates the price right away.

Weirdly, I notice that it DOES update straight away on my local machine, just not on our host's server.

Anyone have any experience or suggestions on what this could be?

Comment: Do you have the cron jobs installed?

Comment: Yes crons up and running

Comment: I don't know if this is applicable to you, but when I faced the same issue, I made a custom API to update the price and just after price update, I did a reindex operation programmatically